# Different SAS inside expiry time interval

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I use shared access signature for my private Azure storage blobs. When I set expiry time 30 minutes for blob and when I call method GetSasForBlobUsingAccessPolicy for first time I get some url with sas, and when I call that same method on same blob for second time (inside 30 minutes interval) I get different sas, and both are valid. Why are they differ? Is it possible to get same one if it is not expired? Is it possible to extend expiry time if sas is expired and get the same sas?

Here are my relevant methods:

```
public void SetBlobContainer( string containerName )
{
    string connectionString = string.Format( @"..." );
    string sharedAccessPolicyName = "my-policy";

    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse( connectionString );

    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference( containerName );

    container.CreateIfNotExists();

    _blobContainer = container;

    if ( !_blobContainer.GetPermissions().SharedAccessPolicies.ContainsKey( sharedAccessPolicyName ) )
    {
        CreateSharedAccessPolicy( sharedAccessPolicyName );
    }
}

public string GetSasForBlob( CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob )
{
    string sasToken = cloudBlockBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature( new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
    {
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes( 30 ),
    }, "my-policy" );
    return string.Format( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}{1}", cloudBlockBlob.Uri, sasToken );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are they differ? Is it possible to get same one if it is not expired?

Each time you call the GetSharedAccessSignature method, you will get a different SAS. Each will have a different start time and expiry time, because you called the method at different times, but they may have the same permissions and other SAS parameters.

You can generate any number of shared access signatures for a blob. Each will be unique, unless the calls are in such close succession that the clock time is the same for each (which is unlikely).

The SAS isn't stored with the blob in any way. It's just a token that's generated that includes the SAS parameters (expiry, permissions, resource, etc.) and the signature. The signature part is used to authenticate a request made using the SAS while it's valid.

So, it isn't possible to generate the same SAS by calling GetSharedAccessSignature within the interval that the SAS is valid. You'll always get a new SAS. But the intervals over which they are valid can overlap, as you've found in working with it.

> Is it possible to extend expiry time if sas is expired and get the same sas?

If you'll need to extend the expiry time on a SAS, you can create a stored access policy on the blob container, and modify the expiry time there. However, you'll need to modify the expiry time *before* the SAS expires. If it expires, you'll need to create a new SAS.

From the documentation, here's the definition of a stored access policy:

A stored access policy is defined on a resource container - a blob container, table, queue, or file share - and can be used to manage constraints for one or more shared access signatures. When you associate a SAS with a stored access policy, the SAS inherits the constraints - the start time, expiry time, and permissions - defined for the stored access policy.

And:

To modify the parameters of the stored access policy, you can call the access control list operation (e.g., CloudBlobContainer.SetPermissions) for the resource type to replace the existing policy, specifying a new start time, expiry time, or set of permissions. For example, if your existing policy grants read and write permissions to a resource, you can modify it to grant only read permissions for all future requests. In this case, the signed identifier of the new policy, as specified by the ID field, would be identical to the signed identifier of the policy you are replacing.

You can have a SAS without an access policy, but it's not possible to extend the expiry time unless you use an access policy.

See [Controlling a SAS with a stored access policy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/#controlling-a-sas-with-a-stored-access-policy) and [Establishing a Stored Access Policy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn140257.aspx) for more information.